# Reduce the space between img and text using css

Tags: html, css

This is my current setup -

css

```
#exportButton {
    float: left;
    background-color: Green;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#exportButton img {
    height: 28px;
    padding: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


#exportLink {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

HTML

```
 <body style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
    <span id="exportButton">
    <a id="exportLink" >HTML</a>
    <img src='http://s26.postimg.org/qpk50nhzp/icn_export.png' height="20px;">
    </span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NJ5Dz/

I need to remove whitespace between Export and the actual picture using CSS..How can I do that?

I tried various options of removing padding/margin but nothing works..

Comment: Take the padding off both, border 0 the image unless you need one. Then also remove the line break between the link and img

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/2888561

Comment: you mean you want to remove whitespace between "HTML" and image ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NJ5Dz/20/ something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the right padding from the link and the left padding from the img.

```
#exportButton {
    float: left;
    background-color: Green;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#exportButton img {
    height: 28px;
    padding: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:0;
}


#exportLink {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NJ5Dz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NJ5Dz/24/

By using a mix of reducing the parent's font-size and margin/padding edits I was able to place them side by side. I did add background color to the image to better show the image beside the text. It is a bit hacky but it works.

**CSS:**

```
#exportButton {
    float: left;
    background-color: Green;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0;
}

#exportButton img {
    height: 28px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}


#exportLink {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```